# WPF Ribbon Contextual Tab Visibility binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, ribboncontrolslibrary

I am finding it surprisingly hard to find examples of binding the visibility of a [RibbonContextualTabGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncontextualtabgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I have a property in my code-behind that should decide when to display a ribbon tab, but everything I've tried so far has no effect. My code-behind is essentially:

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
    public string Port { get; set; }
}
```

A summary of my WPF code is below. I'm looking for a solution that binds the `Visibility` property to whether or not `MainWindow.Port` is `null`.

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow
    ...
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:MagExplorer" />

    ...

    <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="COMTab" 
                      Header="COM"
                      ContextualTabGroupHeader="Communications">
    ...
    </ribbon:RibbonTab>

    <ribbon:Ribbon.ContextualTabGroups>
        <ribbon:RibbonContextualTabGroup Header="Communications"
                                         Visibility="<What goes here?>" />
    </ribbon:Ribbon.ContextualTabGroups>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Converter IsNotNullToVisibilityConverter

with the Convert method like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (value != null)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

And then put it in your XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <IsNotNullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IsNotNullToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
Visibility="{Binding Path=Port, Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

In your code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PortProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register
        ("Port", typeof(String), typeof(NameOfYourClass),
        new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

public String Port
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(PortProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PortProperty, value); }
    }
```

Comment: This is similar to something I've tried, but I can't get it to work. I tried putting a `Console.WriteLine("HERE")` in the `Convert()` but nothing gets printed. Is there something else missing?

Comment: If the Convert method is not called, your binding may be incorrect?
You need to define the ElementName (where the Port property is)
Try to put in your RibbonWindow at the top x:Name="ctl"
and then you binding: Visibility="{Binding Path=Port, ElementName=ctl, Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullToVisibilityConverter}}"

Comment: Oh wait, your Port property need to be a DependencyProperty to be binded, I updated my answer