# WPF RibbonTab extra tools tab (colored in Office)

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribbon-control

Is there any way to set a `RibbonTab` look like the image above?

[image: Tab]

My question isn't specific because I don't know how this tabs are named, only appears when something specific is selected in Office applications.

Comment: You mean to make normal tab look like this? or you need to implement "Contextual Tabs" feature?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel implement that feature, not in normal tabs

Answer (score 1):

This is a contextual tab. I.e. the tabs that are displayed when certain object types are selected, such as the Picture tools. You can add your own custom tab to the existing contexts or add controls to the existing contextual tabs.

Read more about that in the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The special tab which appears based on some context is called as [Ribbon Contextual Tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncontextualtabgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Following example pulled from above link:

```
</ribbon:Ribbon>
    <ribbon:RibbonTab Name="Pens" Header="Pens" ContextualTabGroupHeader="Ink Tools" >
    <!-- Ribbon Tab Content -->
    </ribbon:RibbonTab>
    <ribbon:Ribbon.ContextualTabGroups>
        <ribbon:RibbonContextualTabGroup Header="Ink Tools" Visibility="Visible" Background="Green" />
    </ribbon:Ribbon.ContextualTabGroups>
</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

Also here is a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126430/wpf-ribbon-contextual-tab-visibility-binding) which talks about binding the tab visibility.

Comment: The only thing I need to know was their name, I've searched like "Ribbon colored tabs", "Ribbon extra tabs" or other names, but now I know that are named "Contextual Tabs" and implemented successfully.